# If $X$ is not full rank, is $X(X^TX + \lambda I_p)^{-1}X^T$ invertible if $n < p$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose $X$ is a $n \times p$ matrix with $\text{rank}(X) = r < p$. Is $X(X^TX + \lambda I_p)^{-1}X^T$ invertible when $n < p$?

We know that

$$\operatorname{rank}(X(X^TX + \lambda I_p)^{-1}X^T) \leq \min(\operatorname{rank}(X), \operatorname{rank}((X^TX + \lambda I_p)^{-1}X^T)$$

Since $\operatorname{rank}(X) < p$ and $(X^TX + \lambda I_p)^{-1}X^T$ is a $p \times n$ matrix, then
$$\operatorname{rank}((X^TX + \lambda I_p)^{-1}X^T) \leq \min(n, p) = n$$
therefore,

$$\operatorname{rank}(X(X^TX + \lambda I_p)^{-1}X^T) \leq \min(\operatorname{rank}(X), \operatorname{rank}((X^TX + \lambda I_p)^{-1}X^T)) < n < p$$

Therefore, $X(X^TX + \lambda I_p)^{-1}X^T$ is rank deficient, and thus is not invertible. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $\min(\operatorname{rank}(X), \operatorname{rank}((X^TX + \lambda I_p)^{-1}X^T)) < n < p$

This is not correct. It is possible that the ranks of both $X$ and $(X^TX + \lambda I_p)^{-1}X^T$ are equal to $n$. Also, the inequality $n<p$ will not force $A=X(X^TX + \lambda I_p)^{-1}X^T$ to be rank deficient, since $A$ is $n\times n$.

In general, $A$ can be singular, even if $X$ has full row rank. E.g.
$$
\pmatrix{I_n&0}\left[\pmatrix{I_n\\ 0}\pmatrix{I_n&0}-I_p\right]\pmatrix{I_n\\ 0}=0.
$$

However, if $X$ is a real matrix of full row rank and $\lambda$ is positive, $A$ must be nonsingular, because $A=YY^T$, where $Y=X(X^TX+\lambda I_p)^{-1/2}$ has full row rank. If $Ax=0$, then $\|Y^Tx\|^2=x^TYY^Tx=x^TAx=0$ and hence $Y^Tx=0$. Since $Y^T$ has full column rank, $x$ must be zero.